# Static vs Non-Static Classes

Tags: c#, json

This is what my code looks like in my public Form1()

```
while (accessReader.Read())
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
        string urlpart2= accessReader.GetValue(i).ToString();
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("urlpart1" + urlpart2+ "urlpart3");
        string json;
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        using (var streamr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
           json = streamr.ReadToEnd();
           List<MyObject> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json);
           var date = MyObject.Start;

           //MessageBox.Show(date.ToString());
```

This is my class representing the different variables my json string returns

```
public class MyObject
        {
            public int Type { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string Channel { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public DateTime Start { get; set; }
            public DateTime End { get; set; }
        }
```

This is what a json string will return, the only difference that will change is maybe type, code, start, and end. - **I want the Start and End Values.**

```
[{"Type":1,"Country":"CA","Channel":"","Code":"1EZ","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2015-10-23T00:00:00"},{"Type":2,"Country":"","Channel":"","Code":"UAD","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2017-10-23T00:00:00"},{"Type":2,"Country":"","Channel":"","Code":"TPQ","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2017-10-23T00:00:00"},{"Type":3,"Country":"","Channel":"","Code":"SVC_PRIORITY","Start":"2014-10-24T00:00:00","End":"2017-10-23T00:00:00"}]
```

I am fairly new to programming and I have run into an error I do not really understand 'An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property'.

Also I created this class within my Form1.cs as opposed to creating a new class in my Project Solution (if that matters?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to access `MyObject.Start` like it would be a static property or field. However it's a instance field and basically you need to get a instance to access the field.

```
MyObject obj = list[0];
var date = obj.Start;
```

The field `List<MyObject> list = ...` contains all data which got deserialized from the json file ( And none if no data exists in the json file! ).

I guess you want to access all data of the json file, in this case i would prefer iterating through the objects via a foreach loop.

```
foreach (MyObject item in list) { .... }
```

Comment: Oooooh I see! So in order to seperate them like Type: 1's Start Date and End Date, Type 2's ... and Type 3's ... can I do a `foreach(MyObject type, start, end item in list)()`?

Comment: @Havoux All the data is in a single `MyObject` instance. Iterating through all of them is useful when you have multiple in your json. Or did i misunderstood you?

Comment: Nope you got it 100% Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with line `var date = MyObject.Start;` You have created a list of MyObjects. To access them you have to use list indexes i.e. `var first = list[0]` returns first element. Then you can get required date as: `first.Start`
In order to process every entry of your list you can use `foreach` loop as follows:

```
foreach (var obj in list) {
    // use obj.Start, obj.End values
}
```